# How to zip a folder in MacOS without creating an extra directory inside the zip file

Tags: macos, operating-system, zip

I got a .zip file from my friend and it was compressed under windows, which contains three subfolders inside of it, and when I check the contents of it on my Mac terminal it looks like this:
[image]

Now I unzip this file and then zip it through terminal, and when I check the contents of that zip file it becomes like this:
[image]

I have googled how to zip on mac without creating a subfolder with same name but none of them solves the problem, my question is how to do the zip on Mac which makes the zip file looks exactly same with the initial one I got. 
Thanks very very much

New edit: 
I think I might did not do very well to summarize my problem, so the initial folder contains three sub-folders and all of them were created in windows environment and compressed on windows, when I tried to unzip it on my MacOS machine, the unzipped folder looks still good but when I do the compression on Mac and then view the .zip file through unzip -l xxxx.zip, it is giving me 6 files in which the three sub-folders are also treated as files. Based on my knowledge this is because in BSD systems all the folders are treated as files but in windows they are not, what I'm currently doing is to delete all these files that represent folders through "zip -d", which I know is very silly. I would be more than happy to talk about this from an operating system view with anybody who is interested in it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this command works fine:

```
zip -j zippedFolder.zip myFolder/*
```

To unzip I used

```
unzip zippedFolder.zip
```

and I've got only the data from the folder.

Example: The folder I want to zip is on the desktop and he's called testFolder.

1. Open Terminal
2. cd /Users/yourUser/Desktop
3. zip -f myZip.zip testFolder/*

Comment: Are you in the parentdir from the folder you want to zip?

Comment: yes, lol. btw what i currently have done is using -d option of zip to manually remove all unnecessary files inside that zip file lol.